# How to redirect contact form 7 based upon a checkbox selection in WP?

Tags: wordpress

How to redirect the contactform 7 to a new page based upon a checkbox selection.

My reqiurement is such that if I user checks a option A the contact form 7 should get redirected to a new page whereas if I a user checks option B the contact form 8 should get redirected to a another page.

I tried adding javascript in the message sent successfully box it always shows me a error and doesn't detect the checkbox state.

Comment: Your checkbox stat disappear during redirection. Pass that stat on url and then detect.

Comment: How to do it as it's a ajax one..